# Return the 30th day previous month in excel

Tags: excel

I want to return the 30th of each day for the previous month in excel. I used:

```
EOMONTH(A1,-1)
```

But that will always return the last day of the prevois month. How could you do it so for example the 30th June will return the 30th May NOT 31st May which is returned by the 'EOMONTH' function.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do for March -> return 28th / 29th Feb dependent on Leap Year status, or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perhaps use an `IF()` along with a `TEXT()` to do that.

```
=IF(TEXT(EOMONTH(A1,-1),"dd")="31",EOMONTH(A1,-1)-1,EOMONTH(A41,-1))
```

If the date of `EOMONTH(A1,-1)` is `31`, then take one less day, otherwise, take that date itself.

Comment: @HeadofCatering OP didn't mention anything, so I guessed that there was no problem there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that will also handle February:

```
=MIN(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-1,30),EOMONTH(A1,-1))
```

In other words, take the 30th day of the previous month, or the last day of the previous month, whichever is earlier.  Note that `DATE()` will handle January dates correctly.  According to the help, `DATE()` in this case "...subtracts the magnitude of that number of months, plus 1, from the first month in the year specified. For example, DATE(2008,-3,2) returns the serial number representing September 2, 2007."

Comment: +1 Brian .....but you have a parenthesis in the wrong place, should be MONTH(A1)-1, I think

Comment: @barryhoudini, thanks for spotting that.  I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Brian's solution, but shortened....

`=MIN(EOMONTH(A1,{-2,-1})+{30,0})`